# combining two multidimension arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

i have these two arrays

```
   Array
   (
      [0] => Array
    (
        [text] => 1ofdays.wav
    )

      [1] => Array
    (
        [text] => abcd.mp3
    )

   )



    Array
   (
      [0] => Array
    (
        [value] => 6
    )

       [1] => Array
    (
        [value] => 7
    )

)
```

is there anyway i can combine these two arrays into new array of arrays such that the outcome should be

```
  NewArray
  (
      [0] => Array
    (
        [text] => 1ofdays.wav,
        [value]=>6
    )

     [1] => Array
    (
        [text] => abcd.mp3,,
        [value]=>7
    )

  )
```

and when I will json encode that new array the output should be

```
  [{"text":"1ofdays.wav","value":"6"},{"text":"abcd.mp3","value","7"}]
```

Comment: `array_map(array_merge, $ar1, $ar2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using, `array_map` with `array_merge_recursive` as its callback:

```
$arr1 = [['text' => '1ofdays.wav'], ['text' => 'abcd.mp3']];
$arr2 = [['value' => 6], ['value' => 7]];

$result = array_map('array_merge_recursive', $arr1, $arr2);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => string '1ofdays.wav' (length=11)
      'value' => int 6
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => string 'abcd.mp3' (length=8)
      'value' => int 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with `array_merge`

> https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp